# Typescript scope issue with anonymous self executing function

Tags: typescript

I’ve been testing the new typescript with VS 2012 but I have this issue in my first project:

I have pasted this JS into my ts file but I can't access the Sprite object is its in the anonymous scope. How can I access it from typescript.

```
(function () {
  function LoaderProxy() {
    return {
      draw: $.noop,
      fill: $.noop,
      frame: $.noop,
      update: $.noop,
      width: null,
      height: null
    };
  }

  function Sprite(image, sourceX, sourceY, width, height) {
    sourceX = sourceX || 0;
    sourceY = sourceY || 0;
    width = width || image.width;
    height = height || image.height;

    return {
      draw: function(canvas, x, y) {
        canvas.drawImage(
          image,
          sourceX,
          sourceY,
          width,
          height,
          x,
          y,
          width,
          height
        );
      },

      fill: function(canvas, x, y, width, height, repeat) {
        repeat = repeat || "repeat";
        var pattern = canvas.createPattern(image, repeat);
        canvas.fillColor(pattern);
        canvas.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
      },

      width: width,
      height: height
    };
  };

  Sprite.load = function(url, loadedCallback) {
    var img = new Image();
    var proxy = LoaderProxy();

    img.onload = function() {
      var tile = Sprite(this);

      $.extend(proxy, tile);

      if(loadedCallback) {
        loadedCallback(proxy);
      }
    };

    img.src = url;

    return proxy;
  };

  var spriteImagePath = "images/";

  window.Sprite = function(name, callback) {
    return Sprite.load(spriteImagePath + name + ".png", callback);
  };
  window.Sprite.EMPTY = LoaderProxy();
  window.Sprite.load = Sprite.load;
}());
```

Hope this explains my issue!

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error the compiler gives you is here...

```
Sprite.load
```

It detects that there is no property or function on the Sprite object called `load`.

The second error is here...

```
var tile = Sprite(this);
```

The Sprite constructor takes five parameters and you have only passed 1.

Third up...

```
window.Sprite
```

The Window object doesn't have a property named Sprite.

All of the other problems are variations of this issue.

Here is a suggestion to get things working with minimal changes. The better solution would be to rewrite your Sprite as a class in TypeScript

```
var Sprite;

(function () {
  function LoaderProxy() {
    return {
      draw: $.noop,
      fill: $.noop,
      frame: $.noop,
      update: $.noop,
      width: null,
      height: null
    };
  }

  Sprite = function (image, sourceX, sourceY, width, height) {
    sourceX = sourceX || 0;
    sourceY = sourceY || 0;
    width = width || image.width;
    height = height || image.height;

    return {
      draw: function(canvas, x, y) {
        canvas.drawImage(
          image,
          sourceX,
          sourceY,
          width,
          height,
          x,
          y,
          width,
          height
        );
      },

      fill: function(canvas, x, y, width, height, repeat) {
        repeat = repeat || "repeat";
        var pattern = canvas.createPattern(image, repeat);
        canvas.fillColor(pattern);
        canvas.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
      },

      width: width,
      height: height
    };
  };

  Sprite.load = function(url, loadedCallback) {
    var img = new Image();
    var proxy = LoaderProxy();

    img.onload = function() {
      var tile = Sprite(this);

      $.extend(proxy, tile);

      if(loadedCallback) {
        loadedCallback(proxy);
      }
    };

    img.src = url;

    return proxy;
  };

  var spriteImagePath = "images/";

  Sprite = function(name, callback) {
    return Sprite.load(spriteImagePath + name + ".png", callback);
  };
  Sprite.EMPTY = LoaderProxy();
  Sprite.load = Sprite.load;
}());
```

Comment: Thanks, any chance you could help me write this in TS? The code I posted works fine when used in a JS only page..